# How to show all the images in same line using ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I currently working in ionic3 frameworks

I Need some help

In My Project, I Have a lot of images

I need to show that all images in same line

In the same way, When users try to move images then the image will need to move from right to left

Have any idea to do this??

For example it just like musical app

In musical app there is a topic "new release" under that I need to show all the images in same line.

Comment: check answer and also inform is it working or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in two ways; one using `slides` and also `ion-scroll`. I will suggest use `slides`. Ok will show you `slides` example:

```
  <ion-slides pager="true">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
      <img [src]="slide.MediaUrl">
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

@josh create tutorial for ion-slides [like here](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-sliding-introduction-component-in-ionic-2/)

You can also see official documents [official like](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/)

Comment: i used slides but at the time its shows only one images.I need to show the images continuesly.for ex: when user open the app in mobile they will see first  four images after that if they need to view other images then they wil need to move the screen.how to do that @Utpaul

Comment: its also done by sildes @vignesh.. just visit official link  which i provided

Comment: ok, if there is any chance to add live video streaming in ionic3 just like facebook@Utpaul

Answer (score 0):

Ionic provides a `slides` component. You can use slider component to show all images in horizontal fashion and will be scrollable by the user. Check the component docs here: [slides in ionic 3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#slides)

Alternatively, you can also use, `<ion-scroll>`. you can specify the scroll direction and it will give you a user scrollable area. Docs for `ion-scroll`: [ion-scroll for scrollable area in ionic 3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/)

Answer (score 0):

A simple idea is: There are 3 things:

- A container holds everything (`overflow: auto`)
- Another container holds all your images (`display: inline-flex`)
- Images

```html
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 100%; display: inline-flex">
        <div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" class="image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example my images:

```
.image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

You can read more about Flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Hope this can help.

Comment: its working well,but i need the images moves from right to left not top to bottom

Comment: `display: inline-flex` will make the images list horizontally